# SEO URL customization using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, seo

I am facing an issue during customization of a URL. Here is what I need:

```
http://xyz.com/home/jsjobs/jobseeker/list_jobs/57
```

I want to remove home from all URLs which has home just after my domain name (xyz.com in this case). So, what I want to look like my URL in address bar is:

```
http://xyz.com/jsjobs/jobseeker/list_jobs/57
```

How can I do this using htaccess?

Comment: What do you mean **exactly** by remove? What needs to be done? Do you want permanent redirect (301) from 1st URL to the 2nd (if user types 1ts URL he will be redirected to a 2nd .. which then will be processed)... or you want 2nd URL to be treated behind as 1st URL (user sees 2nd URL but in reality it will be processed as 1st)? Or maybe something else -- please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ http://www.your-url.ext/$1
```